# Why does not MySQL return anything if a table is empty?

Tags: mysql, select

I have 2 tables in MySQL.

> table1: id, title
>     table2: id, title

Now, I would like to see all titles inside both of tables. The problem I have is that if **title** fields contains anything in both tables, I can see returned values. But if one of these tables be empty, I can not see anything even for another table.
This is my query:

```
SELECT
    t1.title as 'title1',
    t2.title as 'title2'
FROM
    table1 t1,
    table2 t1
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: if there's no criteria to join the tables, you may also consider performing a `union all`.

Comment: You need to use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use union

```
Select title from t1
Union 
Select title from t2
```

Comment: @MohammadSaberi Consider giving different column names, in order to avoid conflict. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a LEFT JOIN instead of a CROSS JOIN (which is what the comma operator does here).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

The comma join you are using matches every row in table 1 with every row in table 2. Since there are no rows in table 2, it can't possibly match any of the rows in table 1, and so you get no results. If you want to always see results from table 1, you must use a LEFT JOIN, which pulls all rows from table 1 and *any* matching rows from table 2. If you want to see rows no matter which table has them, you can use a full outer join, which is not directly supported by MySQL but can be emulated (see Google if you want examples).

Comment: How is this related with what the OP has asked?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I really don't know what the OP wants because there isn't enough information about the table structures. Given that he appears to want two different columns and is in fact already trying to perform a join, I figured that explaining how to join properly would be the best answer.

Comment: Its no way related to `join` buddy. It is something like he wants data from both the tables and it is [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) and not Join.

Comment: @siride, I'm not sure the first table contains any data. So what will happen in this condition when using `left join`?

Comment: @MohammadSaberi: you can switch the order of the tables.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I am suspicious of there being two tables with exactly the same columns, so my guess was that there was more going on here. Apparently not. But what you can you do with bad questions on SO these days?

Comment: @siride: And what I have to do if I don't know which one may contains data?

Comment: Well, no idea how to answer this! :| It happens, coz people here would be newbies too!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for this. Make your query this way:

```
SELECT `table1`.`title` as `title1`
UNION
SELECT `table2`.`title` as `title2`;
```